# Not Associated with a Trusted SQL Server Connection (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio-2010, mysql-error-1064

I'm having trouble connectiong to MySQL Server database and get the following error:

Error Message

Login failed for user 'root'. Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

This is the code where the error occurred:

```
        public bool IsValid(string username, string password)
        {

        using (var con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database = timekeeping; Uid = root; Pwd = admin;"))
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())    
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) FROM receptionist WHERE username = @username AND password = @password;";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
            var count = (long)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            return count > 0;
        }
        }
```

Screenshot:

[image]

This is my config file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
 <appSettings>
 <add key="ODBCDriver" value="Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=timekeeping;uid=root;pwd=admin;Option=3;"/>
 </appSettings>
 <connectionStrings>
 <add name="connStr" connectionString="Database=timekeeping;uid=root;pwd=admin;Option=3;" />
 </connectionStrings>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using **MySQL**? The error message clearly states it's *Not associated with a trusted **SQL Server** connection.* I also see you're using SqlConnection (which then implies in SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter, SqlDataReader and so on) which comes from the System.Data.SqlClient namespace - which is specific for SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx (*Represents an open connection to a SQL Server database.*).

To connect to your MySQL database from .NET, you can use ODBC (there may be other options) or if you want to stick to ADO.NET, you can use the [MySQL Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

I guess this should solve it for you. If I'm not mistaken, the Namespace would then be MySql.Data.MySqlClient and the classes would be named MySqlConnection and so on. Not sure about the actual prefixes, namespaces or naming though - on a Mac at the moment. No .NET here :-D

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, the error message bit me - I knew I had looked into the question because it was related to MySQL...

Comment: @leon: if i'm going to use the SqlConnection, should I also change my config file? Because I used ODBCDriver there.

Comment: Please do check my config file

Comment: @schadi
: if you are connecting yo a MYSQL DB, use the mysql provider.

Comment: @schadi: legend says ADO.NET has benefits over ODBC. I personally second Mitch's comment above.

Comment: @mitch and leon: Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should never be querying any database from code as 'root' (unless its code that performs admin tasks; which it isn't in this case)

Are you sure the 'root' password is 'admin'? (hard to guess that one!)

Try using a login that you have connected to your DB with successfully.  i.e. credentials that you can use [MySQL workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) to connect to your DB

Comment: I use root sometimes on my local dev environment.

Comment: @David Ryder : and then what happens when it leaks to production? Use a user/role setup for the task in hand...

Comment: @mitch: yeah I'm pretty sure thatthe "root" password is "admin".

Comment: @Mitch: Production servers won't have the same auth as my local machine - especially since I use phpMyAdmin on my dev. I just don't think it's a big deal to use root @ home/testing

Comment: @David Ryder: it's bad practice IMO.